# How do I disable selections on all objects I have selected?

Tags: scripting

I'm looking to to disable selection all objects I have selected.
I can do 1 at a time but I can't find how to: foreach in current selection group, disable selection objects.

**I edited out the code due to people thinking it was mine lol**

Answer (score 5):

You normally do this sort of thing with a for loop; using `bpy.context.selected_objects`.  That's a list of all of the objects you have selected.

Here's an example:

```py
import bpy
for object in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    print(object.name)
    object.hide_select = True
```

This isn't exactly what you asked for.  The 3rd line is debugging and prints the names of the objects it's deselecting.  Take it out if you don't want the noise.

EDIT:  Having the broken code in my answer is confusing people in the comments. I've removed it and left only my working code above.

Comment: also notice that the SEL_OBJS line should be separated by a return from the ACT_OBJ line because they are two separate statements.

Comment: Cheers, I wasn't trying to write code, I was just giving an idea what I wanted by looking online for examples.

Comment: @MarcVolkers  My first example above will do what you wanted.  So would the code you posted, formatted the way I have it now.

Comment: fwiw I don't think that even indented properly the original code would work, `bpy.context.object` points to the active object, so the loop will make the same object unselectable many times. Also although it's valid in this context maybe a word of warning that using `object` in python is not advised since it overrides the base type `object`. And making an object unselectable automatically unselects it from the viewport (not from the outliner though) :)

Comment: @Gorgious you're absolutely right on `bpy.context.object` and on unselect.  Editing answer now.

Comment: It's not freezing the entire group still, just 1 out of max group

Comment: The top code should be freezing the entire group.  As we discussed in the comments, the second one, as written, isn't. So I removed the second one to avoid confusion.

Comment: Youtube video showing it's only freezing one object in selected objects. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X3OO1GpUNaA  | I'm running the script through pie menus,

Comment: You're not running the script @MarcVolkers.   If you're invoking the code from a pie menu that means you stuffed it in an operator.  Edit your question and show the actual code from the operator, probably the `execute` routine, and I'll update my answer.  (Hint: the operator takes a `context` variable, so you want to use it instead of `bpy.context`.)

Comment: How do I make this work for the pie menu :) I'm a novice in python. I see in running in the scripting window, but I kinda need it working as a fast command (how do I convert this so i can call it via hotkey, piemenu etc)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135234/discussion-between-marty-fouts-and-marc-volkers).

Comment: Just out of curiosity wouldn't `for object in list(bpy.context.selected_objects):` be safer execution since setting `object.hide_select = True` is modifying `bpy.context.selected_objects` each loop iteration?

Comment: @Ratt It would be safer, because it would prevent mistakes if the code was later modified to add something that changed `selected_objects`, and yes it is possible that setting `hide_select` might reorder `selected_objects`.  Good spot.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at proper code formatting in python. Formatting and indentation are essential for python code. If you don't follow the rules, your code will not work as intended.

You have to indent the content of a for loop. And there must not be any blank line between the header and the content of a for loop.

Comment: Cheers, I wish I never wrote anything :S I deleted it, I'm looking for some one to write something or point me in the right direction.